# Opening registry key in c

Tags: c, winapi, registry

I have create a key using regedit, now I want to get its value. It doesn't give any error but it isn't showing anything.
Code :

```
int main() {
    HKEY hKey;
    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Ehsan Akbari", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
    TCHAR sz[50];
    DWORD size = 50,type;
    RegEnumValue(hKey, 0, L"test", &size, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)sz, &size);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

An image of regedit :[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyim3.png)

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

---

When I debugged I saw that `hKey` is `NULL`, but `GetLastError` doesn't report anything.

Comment: You forgot the part where you print the value you got to the screen. You also do no error checking, which would help with the `hKey` being `NULL`.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't give any error when you don't check for any error. Anyway your screenshot shows the key under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and you're trying to open it under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Comment: Look at the docs -- `RegOpenKeyEx` doesn't report errors via `GetLastError()`

Comment: I didn't put error checking because I wanted to write a very quick example of registry in win32 but I debugged it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the immediate problems that I can see:

1. You detect no errors because you don't check for errors. Read the documentation for each function. The error code is returned in the return value.
2. You ask for `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` which won't be granted under `HKLM`. You need to request just read access `KEY_READ`.
3. Your screenshot shows the key has been created under `HKCU`, and you're trying to open it under `HKLM`.
4. `RegEnumValue` expects the size of the data buffer in bytes. You pass the length, the number of characters.
5. You are mixing Unicode literals and `TCHAR`. This is pointless. Your code won't compile targeting MBCS and in any case you don't care about Win98 any more. Stop using `TCHAR` and use `wchar_t` instead.
6. The `lpValueName` parameter must be a modifiable buffer. You pass a literal. Remember that this function enumerates values. It does not read specific named values as perhaps you expect.
7. The `lpcchValueName` parameter contains the size of the buffer you passed to `lpcchValue` in characters. You pass the length of the data buffer.
8. The data returned may not be null terminated. You must protect against this as described in the documentation.
9. For a C program which ignores its arguments, the correct `main` is `int main(void)`.

I expect there are more errors but I stopped looking at this point. I recommend you spend some quality time with the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To open the path "Ehsan Akbari" in HKEY_CURRENT_USER you could try this:

```
HKEY hKey;
long result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER , TEXT("\\Ehsan Akbari"), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);

if ( result == ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    cout << "OK" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Error " << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's in c my program is in C not C++